# C++ Creating variables from protected abstract/derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, derived-class

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong with creating variables from a  derived class. I have the abstract class, the derived class and am trying to create the derived class as a variable in the main testing program.  However I get the error: no matching function for call to DerivedPlayer::DerivedPlayer()’.  I haven't been able to find the correct syntax as to create and initialize a variable of the derived class.  Also note that the abstract class's constructor is protected.

Abstract Header (Base.h)

```
    #ifndef BASE_H_
    #define BASE_H_

    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    class Base {
      public:
        virtual ~Base() {}

      protected:
        Base(std::string s) : x(0), s(s), v(0) {}

        int x;
        std::string s;
        std::vector<int> v;
    };
    #endif
```

Derived Header (Derived.h)

```
    #ifndef DERIVED_H_
    #define DERIVED_H_

    #include "Base.h"

    class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Derived(std::string name){ s = name; }
        virtual ~Derived();
    };

    #endif
```

Test Code (InTest.cpp)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Derived.h"

    int main() {

        Derived a = Derived("R2-D2");
        Derived b = Derived("C-3PO");

        return 0;
    }
```

Build Log

```
    03:23:52 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project InTest ****
    make all 
    Building file: ../src/InTest.cpp
    Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
    g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/InTest.d" -MT"src/InTest.o" -o "src/InTest.o" "../src/InTest.cpp"
    In file included from ../src/InTest.cpp:2:0:
    ../src/Derived.h: In constructor ‘Derived::Derived(std::string)’:
    ../src/Derived.h:8:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
      Derived(std::string name){ s = name; }
                               ^
    ../src/Derived.h:8:27: note: candidates are:
    In file included from ../src/Derived.h:4:0,
                     from ../src/InTest.cpp:2:
    ../src/Base.h:12:2: note: Base::Base(std::string)
      Base(std::string s) : x(0), s(s), v(0) {}
      ^
    ../src/Base.h:12:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    ../src/Base.h:7:7: note: Base::Base(const Base&)
     class Base {
           ^
    ../src/Base.h:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    make: *** [src/InTest.o] Error 1

    03:23:52 Build Finished (took 214ms)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output you get.

Comment: The full error was posted in the OP and is : ../src/Derived.h:8:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’.  The entire compile log is too large to post as a comment.

Comment: You should post the full error (including informational notes etc.) in the *question body*. Please *edit your question*. And please try to create an [mcve] to show us, because with the code you show the `DerivedPlayer` default constructor should not be used, so the error message you show doesn't fit the code you currently show.

Comment: The code has been revised with a build log included.

Comment: I don't see an abstract class here. Did you intended to have an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main part of the error message:

```
../src/Derived.h: In constructor ‘Derived::Derived(std::string)’:
../src/Derived.h:8:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
  Derived(std::string name){ s = name; }
```

Because `Derived` inherits from `Base`, each time a `Derived` object is constructed the `Base` class constructor also have to run. The problem with your current code is that you let the default `Base` constructor be called, but there isn't any.

You solve it by "calling" the correct `Base` constructor in the `Derived` constructor initializer list:

```
Derived::Derived(std::string name)
    : Base(name)
{}
```